# Disjunctive question on the word "dislike"

Tags: tag-questions

- You dislike math, do you?
- You dislike math, don't you?

So confusing. Which one is right?

Answer (score 5):

Both forms have their uses, so neither is wrong.

"You dislike math, do you?" suggests that *you* have just made it clear to the questioner that *you* do indeed dislike math, and the questioner is about to challenge *you* on it.

"You dislike math, don't you?" suggests that the questioner is inferring that *you* dislike math, and is asking for confirmation.

But you have to be a native English speaker - any flavor - to grok subtleties like this.

Comment: It's funny how we natives can hear the confrontational tone of the first one, even in print. Good answer.

Answer (score 3):

English has a couple of patterns for forming interrogative clauses, i.e., for asking questions.  One is to invert the subject and verb from a declarative sentence, in which the **verb** ordinarily follows the subject.

> Math **is** hard (*declarative*)

becomes

> **Is** math hard? (*interrogative*)

This may require the addition of an auxiliary verb like *do*:

> Mary **likes** math (*declarative*)

becomes

> **Does** Mary like math? (interrogative)

A second way to ask a question is follow a declarative clause with what's called an *interrogative tag*, which takes a **pronoun** whose antecedent is the subject of the declarative clause.

> Mary likes math, *doesn't **she***?

Here the pronoun *she* refers to Mary.

The tags have the reverse polarity of the declarative clause, i.e., if the declarative clause does have a negative particle (*not*, *-n't*), then the tag does not have a negative particle.  If the declarative clause does not have a negative particle, then the tag does.  Since the statement *Mary likes math* does not contain a *not*, the tag *doesn't she?* contains one (hidden in the contraction *n't*).  If we reverse the polarity:

> Mary doesn't like math, does she?

the declarative statement contains a *not* (in *doesn't*), so the tag *does she?* lacks one.

Notice that when you use the first pattern, you don't use a tag.  So you would not say

> Does Mary like math, doesn't she? (*ungrammatical*)

Here *Does Mary like math?* has the form of a question (subject following verb), so it cannot take a tag.

However, it is possible for the declarative statement and the tag to have the same polarity:

> Mary dislikes math, does she?

But in this case, it's not really a question, but a challenge or expression of disbelief or astonishment.  It means "You say that Mary dislikes math, but I'm so surprised to hear that, that I don't believe it."  Even though the same-polarity tag is punctuated with a question mark, it won't be spoken with the final rising pitch that indicates a query.  Same polarity tags don't work with negative particles:

> Mary doesn't like math, doesn't she? (*ungrammatical*)

Answer (score 0):

"You dislike math, don't you" is the correct form. "You dislike math, do you" is contradicting yourself.

*Also, might want to fix the punctuation in your post. Can be hard to interpret.*

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that this is confusing.

In effect, one is asking a question by:

- making a statement, then
- almost *daring* the receiver to refute it

The asker in this case really believes his own answer to the question, and doesn't really care what the receiver's true answer is. They are being pushed into agreeing, by being dared to disagree - hence the "don't" rather than the "do".

A better way to ask the question would be "Do you dislike math?"

This would then give the receiver of the question the freedom to answer as they see fit, rather than knowing that the asker already has a preconceived answer.